# Easy ways to get music discs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was thinking of an easy way to get music disc.
I got an idea that putting a creeper in a fence and then making a archer hit him

```
Top view
  ###
  #C#  C is creeper
  ###  these are fences
```

but here trapping the creeper was a big problem as if I get close it would explode.
i think there must be some easy ways to get music discs. What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried trapping a skeleton/creeper in this format?
(Being that 'P' = Player, 'C' = Creeper, 'S' = Skeleton and '#' is the fence.)

```
Top View
 ###
 #S#
 ###
      <Leave a gap...>
 ###
 #C#
 ###
      <Leave another gap...>
 ###
  P
```

Just make sure that the skeleton is targeting you.
Basically, because the aiming of a mob is based on where their sight of you, while seeing through other entities, the skeleton will shoot straight at the creeper, as it does not take the creeper into consideration when targetting you.

**This is what the Skeleton sees:**

```
Top View
 ###
 #S#
 ###
      <Leave a gap...>
 ###
 # #  <Creeper isn't there, in the eye of the skeleton.>
 ###
      <Leave another gap...>
 ###
  P
```

In the eye of the creeper, it does not see the skeleton unless it is the last thing that attacked it. This setup also works because the Creeper is at least 2 blocks from the Skeleton (so that the creeper does not blow up).

Comment: Yes i actually did that. But the toughest part is getting creeper and skeleton within those fences.

Comment: Try boxing yourself in a hole, one lower than ground. Then when it walks up to the block directly in front of you, place the fence to cover it.

Comment: Well this is one idea to get music discs i will wait for some more ideas to come and at last i  will accept the best of all.